# Selecting all from one table and join the most recent association from another table

Tags: mysql, join, sequelize.js

I have two tables, `sensors` and `readings`. I need to list all entries in `sensors` with the most recent value from `readings`. `readings` table has a foreign key pointing to `sensors`. How do I accomplish this with Sequelize?

Here is what should happen:

```
sensors:

---------------
| id | name   |
---------------
| 1  | Test   |
---------------
| 2  | Test 2 |
---------------

readings:

---------------------------------------------
| id | sensor | value | time                |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2      | 25.5  | 2016-06-14 17:01:50 |
---------------------------------------------
| 2  | 2      | 23.5  | 2016-06-14 17:04:50 |
---------------------------------------------
| 3  | 1      | 21.7  | 2016-06-14 17:06:00 |
---------------------------------------------

result:

---------------------------------------------
| id | name   | value | time                |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | Test   | 21.7  | 2016-06-14 17:06:00 |
---------------------------------------------
| 2  | Test 2 | 23.5  | 2016-06-14 17:04:50 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is considered most recent?

Comment: @LT- The one which has the newest time value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/) of `sequelizejs` to do this;)

```
sequelize.query(
    'select s.*, r.value, r.time' +
    'from sensors s ' +
    'left join readings r on s.id = r.sensor' +
    'and (r.sensor, r.time) in (' +
    'select sensor, max(time) from readings group by sensor' +
    ')', 
    {type : sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Sequelize as I'm trying to avoid using raw queries. I believe there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you model your relations correctly, you should be able to perform a query like this:

```
models.sensors.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.readings,
        order: [['time', 'DESC']],
        limit: 1
    }],
    order: [['id', 'ASC']]
}).then(results => results.map(result => {
    return {
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        value: result.readings[0].value,
        time: result.readings[0].time
    }
})).then(results => {
    // The rest of your logics here...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I can tell this seems to result in the right values, but the query it executes is extremely complicated and with more entries in the database I believe it is going to be very slow. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could try to use paging. So instead of loading everything at once (which would be very slow), try separating them into different pages by playing around with the limit and offset

Comment: Pagination results in faster queries, but it isn't a good solution for what I'm trying to achieve.